# How to distinguish: when you can swap "de" with "en" and when you cannot?

Tags: vocabulaire, constructions, pronoms-personnels

> 1) Je me suis occupée **de** faire ...

The phrase "s'occuper de faire" can easily be turned into:

> 1+) Je m'**en** suis occupée.

As to the phrase "se jurer de faire", on the other hand:

> 2) Je me suis jurée **de** ne jamais faire ...

... it is uncommon, if not impossible, to say:

> 2+) Je m'**en** suis jurée.

On the surface, these two phrases take essentially  the same form, but what grammatical rule dictates when you can replace "de" with "en" and when you cannot? What splits phrasal verbs like these into these two groups?

Comment: Your question is not about when you can "replace" *de* with *en* because you **never** can, *en* is a personal pronoun and *de* is a preposition. You use *en* to replace an **indirect object** introduced by *de* (*Je me suis occupée de **ranger les courses***, *ranger les courses* is an indirect object of *occuper de*). *Jurer* is followed by a **direct object** (*le* or *la*) (*J'ai juré / promis **de venir*** / *je l'ai juré* / *promis*). The question could be why does  *jurer* have a direct object preceded by *de*.

Comment: @Alone-zee think *"take care **of** X"* vs *"swear [that] **X**"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On ne peut **jamais** remplacer *en* (pronom personnel)  par *de* (préposition).

*En* remplace un **complément d'objet indirect** précédé de *de (d', du, de la , de l', des*).

- Je me suis occupé de **ranger les courses**.
  Le verbe est *s'occuper **de***, suivi d'un **complément d'objet indirect**.
  → Je m'**en** suis occupé.

Dans la phrase :

- J'ai juré (ou je me suis juré) de ne jamais regretter mes décisions.
  Le verbe est *jurer*, suivi d'un **complément d'objet direct** :
  →  Je **l**'ai juré. /Je me **le** suis juré.

Donc la question est de savoir pourquoi, dans les exemples donnés, deux verbes de construction semblable **en apparence**  sont suivis l'un d'un **complément d'objet direct**, l'autre d'un **complément d'objet indirect**.

***S'occuper de*** : la préposition fait partie du verbe, c'est un verbe transitif **indirect**.

***Jurer*** : *de* ne fait pas partie du verbe mais sert à marquer l'infinitif qui suit. « Le marqueur d’infinitif précède le verbe quand celui-ci est en position de complément d’objet direct d’un autre verbe »<sup>1</sup>.  C'est un verbe transitif **direct**.

Pour un non natif savoir si le *de* fait partie du premier verbe ou sert à marquer l'infinitif du verbe qui suit fait partie de l'**apprentissage du vocabulaire**. Un francophone, ou un non francophone de niveau déjà avancé, ne se pose pas plus la question que de savoir si un nom est masculin ou féminin.

Pour savoir s'il va utiliser le pronom *en* (complément d'objet indirect)  soit :

- il se pose la question *de qui / de quoi* :
  De quoi me suis-je occupée ? (de quoi -> objet indirect)
- ou il remplace l'infinitif par un nom :
  -> je me suis occupée **de** ma sœur. (-> Je m'en suis occupée)
  *De* fait bien partie de *s'occuper de* puisqu'on la garde même si on remplace l'infinitif par un nom commun.

Pour savoir s'il va utiliser les pronoms  *le*, *la* ou *les* (objets directs) soit :

- il se pose la question *qui / quoi / que :
  Qu'est-ce que j'ai juré ? J'ai juré quoi ? (que -> objet direct)
- ou il remplace par un nom :
  Je me suis juré (promis) le silence. (Pas de préposition devant le nom, c'est donc que le *de* servait à marquer l'infinitif.

<sup>1</sup>   <sub>« [Intégrer les marqueurs d’infinitif dans la grammaire française](https://gerflint.fr/Base/Paysscandinaves3/kalmbach.pdf) ». Jean-Michel Kalmbachlmbach *Synergies Pays Scandinaves* n° 3 - 2008 pp. 63-74. Article que j'ai trouvé éclairant sur cette notion pas toujours facile à expliquer.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The correct form for your second example is:

> Je **me l'** étais jurée …

By the way, first sentence is in "passé composé" while the second one is in "plus-que-parfait", for the sake of clarity you should have the same tenses for both sentences

So the second sentence should be:

> Je **me le** *suis* jurée …

As for why there is different forms I don't know. I don't have a reference about that but I think most pronominal verbs use "m'en" but a few exceptions use "me le" or its derivatives.

Comment: "As for why there is different forms I don't know."  *s'occuper de* is an indirect transitive verb,  *jurer* is a direct transitive verb.  "most pronominal verbs use "m'en" but a few exceptions use "me le"" : nothing to do with "pronominal verbs": *Je jure de le faire* -> *Je le jure*.

Comment: @VivienGarcia not knowing the gender of **l'**, I would write it as : *Je me l' étais jur**é***.